# List comprehension returns an empty list

Tags: python, list, syntax, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a function which traverses a file for words with a certain tag and then puts these words in a list by using list comprehension. However, my function returns an empty list instead.

This is the code:

```
 with gzip.open(gzfile) as fhand:
        line = [line.split(b' ') for line in fhand]
        neutrum = [word for word in line if b'/NN|NEU' in word]
```

So basically I want words containing '/NN|NEU' to be put in neutrum, but like I said, the function keeps return neutrum as empty.

When I use the following code the function works as excpected:

```
neutrum = []
for line in fhand:
    line = line.split(b' ')
    for word in line:
        if b'/NN|NEU' in word:
            neutrum.append(word)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there are two `for` loops in your two list comprehensions, those two loops are iterating the same things -- the lines in the file (once as strings, then as lists). Thus, you are just iterating lines and checking whether that neutrum-indicating string is in the *line*, not in a *word* in the line.

Instead, use two `for` loops in your list comprehension to mimic your nested loops:

```
lines = [line.split(b' ') for line in fhand] # all the lines, not a single line
neutrum = [word for line in lines  # <-- this loop was missing
                for word in line
                if b'/NN|NEU' in word]
```

Or, probably a bit cleaner, in a single list comprehension (can also be on one line if you prefer):

```
neutrum = [word for line in fhand
                for word in line.split(b' ')
                if b'/NN|NEU' in word]
```